# jquery caching in object

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.nav ul li a').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var obj = {};

    $('.cnt').load(url + ' div', function (response) {
        obj['key'] = $(this).html();
    });

    return false;
});
```

My problem is that every time I click, the obj only gets the key once. I want on every next click the object to hold the previous key and add the new one. It should look something like this:

```
1st click obj{key}

2nd click obj{key,key}
```

now it looks like this:

```
1st click obj{key}

2nd click obj{key}
```

Comment: An object's keys must be unique. The second time you set 'key' it is just overwriting the first one.

Comment: then what should i do so it doesnt overwrite but adds the new one

Comment: Two things: move `obj` outside of the `click` function definition, and come up with a method so that each "key" is unique.

Comment: can u give me a little hint about the unique part

Answer (score 0):

An object can only have one value per key.  You're setting the `'key'` value of `obj`, so it's re-setting that key each time.

You want to be using an array instead.

```
var arr = [];
$('.nav ul li a').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    $('.cnt').load(url + ' div', function (response) {
        arr.push($(this).html());
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: then what should i do so it doesn't re-set but adds a new key with a new value

Comment: @techfoobar: Oops, I didn't realize that >.<

Comment: @solenoo: You should do what you just said.  Add a new key, instead of re-using the old one.  That's why I suggested an array instead of an object.